# CURL's HTTPS redirection is working in local, but not on the server

Tags: php, redirect, curl, https

I am working on a website aiming to modify all of the ALT attributes of a given URL.
So I have a main page containing an iframe which displays the content of URL. 
This content is displayed thanks to CURL (I had to use CURL to display the page instead of usual iframe's SRC attribute due to the cross-domain policy). 
The problem is, if I enter an http:// protocol URL whereas the website is located on a https:// one, the page doesn't redirect to the https. I used this CURL options to make it working :

$options = array(

```
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // return headers 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects 
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings 
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i 
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect 
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response 
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects 
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
```

);

But unfortunately, it is only working on the local server. When I try it one my own server, the redirection is not working. 
When I check for the curl errors, nothing appears.

Here is the website to give a test:

http://clem.dev.platetec.com/alt-modifier/get-page.php?url=https://fastcoding.jp

Is it a server problem ? If someone could give me a hint, it would help me a lot !
Thank you.

Comment: may be curl extension not enable on your server.

Comment: You could try [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) and also to print the server response headers.

Comment: @hardiksolanki It seems to be enabled because the https page can be displayed

Comment: @ClémentGournay : https and curl both are different thing. Do one thing just create phpinfo file and upload it your on server then run your phpinfo file and check your curl extension enable or not on server.

Comment: @machineaddict When I type a http:// url, the server returns the response code 301, and when I type https:// url, the server returns code 200.. Shouldn't it be the contrary ?

Comment: @hardiksolanki What I meant is, if curl wasn't enabled, I wouldn't be able to load any page with curl right ? Every page is generated by curl. But I'm gonna check anyway as you said thanks.

Comment: Yeah you won't be able to call any curl function without curl extension, glad to help you...